Lower bound for orbits of action of a finite group
The exercise starts with the following auxiliary lemma:
Let $x_1,x_2 \ldots x_n$ be positive integers such that $\frac{1}{x_1}+\ldots+\frac{1}{x_n}=1$ then $\max(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n) \leq n^{2^{n-1}}$
Then let $G$ be a group acting on itself by conjugation and let $k$ be the number of orbits of this action, show that $|G| \leq k^{2^{k-1}}$
I have managed to prove this one using this lemma, the class equation and orbit stabilizer theorem, since that $G$ is decomposed into disjoint orbits by this action the size of each orbit of $x$ is $[G:\mathrm{Stab}(x)]$ applying the lemma and the class equation we are done.
But I am struggling with the second part that asks to prove that if $|G|=n$ then the number of orbits
$$ k \geq \frac{\log(\log(n))}{\log(4)}.$$
I really don't know how to manipulate this what I got to reach the desired result. Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Did you try Burnside's lemma here?  It gives an expression for the number of orbits.

This exercise is essentially asking you to reproduce a paper by Morris Newman [1]. You can find the full solution there.
If you want to try solve it for yourself (which I recommend), I'll give two tips:

Start from the weaker inequality $n \leq k^{2^k}$.
Use the trivial inequality $\log k \leq 2^k$.

[1] Newman, Morris, A bound for the number of conjugacy classes in a group, J. Lond. Math. Soc. 43, 108-110 (1968). ZBL0157.35403.

Unfortunately I do not have access to this paper, but I think I got a solution. We know that $n \leq k^{2^{k-1}}$ . Taking log2 on both sides and using this trivial inequality we get $\log_2(n) \leq2^{k}$, so $\log_2(log_2(n)) \leq k$, and now by analysing the basis we know that $\log_4(log_{10}(n))$ is less or equal to $\log_2(log_2(n))$ and we are done. Is it correct?

I don't think the way you're getting to $\log_2 n \leq 2^k$ is correct. Regardless, you're making this more difficult than it needs to be by working with different bases for the logarithms. Starting from the weaker inequality $n \leq k^{2^k}$, taking the logarithm on both sides you get $\log n \leq 2^k \log k$. Now apply the trivial inequality...
